zsh error setting prompt, NOT using oh-my-zsh
I am having trouble setting the dracula theme for zsh. I am NOT using oh-my-zsh.
I have downloaded the theme and I have placed it in the correct folder. When I run
~/ prompt -l
dracula adam1 adam2 bart bigfade clint default elite2 elite fade fire off oliver pws redhat restore suse walters zefra

I can see right there that the theme is seen. When I do
~/ prompt dracula 
set_prompt:98: prompt_dracula_setup: function definition file not found

I get that error. The instructions listed here show how to install with oh-my-zsh but I dont want that.
Dracula Zsh Theme instructions
I followed the instructions listed here
Arch Linux Zsh Manual install prompt theme
I moved the lib folder that came with the theme into the .zprompts/ folder and had the file async.zsh sourced after I added .zprompts/ to my $fpath
here is my .zshrc file
# Lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
HISTFILE=~/.histfile
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=1000
setopt autocd extendedglob notify
bindkey -v
# End of lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
# The following lines were added by compinstall
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/alex/.zshrc'

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
# End of lines added by compinstall
# Adding completion with menu



zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
# Adding zprompts to fpath(zsh looks here)
fpath=("$HOME/.zprompts" "$fpath[@]")
#autoload -Uz async
source $HOME/.zprompts/lib/async.zsh
autoload -Uz async && async
#adding colors with prompt themes
autoload -Uz promptinit && promptinit
prompt fade blue

Any questions or comments more than welcome. Thank you for your help and especially your time.

When I created the symlink. I did mkdir to make the folder which I thought what it was doing but a symlink is not to a folder so I have to do more reading.
However I have a different issue now.

As an answer, this is a bit vague. An answer is supposed to help people with a similar problem. Perhaps you could describe in more detail what the problem was, and how you resolved it. Also, remove sentence abbout "different issue", which for sure is not an answer to your original problem.
